# Source of the fact that $(1+a_n)^{b_n} \to e^c$ if $a_nb_n \to c$ and $a_n \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

There exists a known fact about the convergence of certain sequences, which is as follows:

If $a_n \to 0$ and $a_nb_n \to c$, then $(1+a_n)^{b_n} \to e^c$.

This is similar to the definition of $e$ as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$, but more general.

I am looking for a *source* of this fact, not directly for a proof. It could be a proven theorem in a book, but it is also alright if it is stated as an exercise left to the reader.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$\left(1+a_n\right)^{b_n}=e^{b_n\ln(1+a_n)}=e^{b_na_n\cdot \frac{\ln(1+a_n)}{a_n}}.$$

Comment: *“I am looking for a **source** of this fact, not directly for a proof.”*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as Martin R kindly pointed out, this is useless for my needs. I hope this helps anybody else who goes searching for this fact, but I need specifically the source. I checked Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis but I didn't find it there.

Comment: Isn't a proof a "source" ? @MartinR

Comment: I also tried Fichtenholz and the problem set by Kaczor and Nowak, and asked multiple(!) professors who all confirmed the fact to be true  and well known but could not give me a source, except for one who pointed to the 13 years old lecture notes of another professor, who also did not know where he got it from.